# Can electromagnetic fields be measured from a distance?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

I know that direct measurements of electromagnetic fields can only tell information about the field near the probes, but I am curious if there is a way to measure the electromagnetic field in a not too distant point of space(about 1-2 meters).

Comment: I can't think of any way to do it without putting some sort of probe there ...

Comment: As long as the field can propagate away from the source and it is not strongly damped by the medium, then yes.  You could do this with a monopole or dipole antenna or a search coil.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, NO, there is not a way to measure an electromagnetic field (in a vacuum) at a point without placing a probe at that point.  In a strongly nonlinear medium the refractive index and the local birefringence of the medium may be affected by the electromagnetic field in such a way that the field can be mapped out by distant sensors; but even in that case it would be necessary to use a laser or somesuch light source to *probe* the effects of the electromagnetic field on the medium.  And the medium itself could be considered to be a probe.

It's a bit ironic: we write field equations that *assume* we know the field everywhere, but there really isn't a way to measure the field everywhere.  Instead, we measure at a few points and use our knowledge of the apparatus and Maxwell's equations to infer the field values everywhere else.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, they can. Suspend a first surface mirror from a thread. Attach the mirror to the thread with two small magnets. Direct a laser onto the mirror so that the reflected laser is projected on a distance target. Shake a magnet in front of the hanging mirror. The laser will show the mirrors reaction. A typical ceramic magnet should be detectable out to 100 feet. To detect a pulsating current through a wire create a wire loop, and with a hand switch pulse current through the wire.  See my video. It shows how it all works. https://youtu.be/53RVKc5R2bs

Comment: The suspended mirror+magnets *are* a probe, which the OP specifically excludes.

Comment: @S.McGrew where does the OP say that. Read the question, no mention of that.

Comment: Looks like we interpreted the question differently.  Perhaps the OP will explain the question in more detail.